# creating a javascript dice object

Tags: javascript-objects

I need to create a "Dice" object using javascript.  I have the start but am running into some fundamental errors.

```
var Die = function (){
    this.sides = 6;
}
var Die = function (value){
   this.sides = value;
}
Die.prototype.roll = function(){
    var result = Math.floor((Math.random()*sides)+1);
    return;
}
Die.prototype.getValue = function(){
    return sides;
}
```

I want to have a default six sided die but if the user wants to add a different number of sides they should have that option, hence the attempt at an overloaded constructor.  the roll method is supposed to simulate "rolling".

I don't really know where I am going wrong but my methods are not working
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Your first two statements are overriding each other, you should combine them into one, as follows.

```
var Die = function(sides) {
  this.sides = sides || 6;
}
```

The only error in your `roll` and `getValue` methods is that to access the `sides` variable you must use `this.sides`, as it is a property of the `Die` object. The two functions can also be combined into one quite easily.

```
Die.prototype.roll = function() {
  return Math.floor((Math.random()*this.sides)+1);
}
```

Example usage:

```
var die = new Die();
console.log(die.roll()); // --> 4
var five_sided_die = new Die(5);
console.log(five_sided_die.roll()); // --> 3
```